# Understanding references in Python

Tags: python, reference

Following example:

```
a = 1
b = a
b = 3
print(a) # gives 1
```

But, when I do:

```
a = [1,2]
b = a
b[0] = 3
print(a) # gives [3,2]
```

How do I know whether a variable is treated like a (C++ type) reference or a plain variable? Are elementary data types just an exception to the 'everything is a reference' rule? What detail of the underlying mechanics am I missing?

Comment: Python is not C.  In python a name references an object.  In the first case you re assign a name to a new object.  In the second case, you assign a second name to the same object, and then play with the object

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For a better grasp of this kind of issues, I would encourage you to use the **Online Python Tutor**. This is an extremely handy tool that renders a graphical representation of the objects in memory while the code is executed step by step.

To show the Online Python Tutor in action I have splitted a toy example into small snippets and then captured the corresponding screenshots. Hopefully this will help you figure out how Python referencing works.

```
a = 1
b = a
```

[image: Step 1]

```
b = 2
```

[image: Step 2]

```
x = [a, b]
y = x
```

[image: Step 3]

```
y[1] = 3
```

[image: Step 4]

If you want to play around with this code, follow [this link](http://www.pythontutor.com/visualize.html#code=a+%3D+1%0Ab+%3D+a%0Ab+%3D+2%0Ax+%3D+%5Ba,+b%5D%0Ay+%3D+x%0Ay%5B1%5D+%3D+3&mode=display&origin=opt-frontend.js&cumulative=false&heapPrimitives=true&textReferences=false&py=2&rawInputLstJSON=%5B%5D&curInstr=0).

Answer (score 3):

*All* variables in Python are references. Elementary data types aren't an exception.

In the first example, you *reassign* `b`. It no longer references the same object as `a`.

In the second example, you *modify* `b`. Since you've previously set `a` and `b` to be references to the same object, the modification applies to `a` as well.

Comment: But this just shifts the question. Why does the third line in both examples once acts as reassignment and once as modification? Why does `b[0]` reference to the same object as `a[0]`, but not `b` and `a`?

Comment: @bluenorange the syntax `x[y] = z` is special, it gets converted by Python to `x.__setitem__(y, z)` rather than doing a reassignment. See https://docs.python.org/2/reference/datamodel.html#object.__setitem__

Comment: You can only reassign names, not array elements. `a = 5` or `a = [1,2]` (re-)assigns the identifier `a`, while `a[0] = 5` means "dereference `a` and change the first value to 5". `b = a` assigns `b` to whatever `a` points to.

Comment: Another point is that in the first example `a` and `b` point to immutable objects in memory, so `a` and `b` point at the same number, but that number cannot change in memory. If you then increment `b` for example like `b += 3`, it will actually point to another immutable object/number in memory, and not change the value `a` points to.

Answer (score 0):

Every name is a plain reference.

A variable name is a reference to an object, and what matters is the properties of the object.  Rule:  numbers (int, float, etc.), strings, tuples (and others) are *immutable* - read-only.  Lists, dictionaries, sets (and others) are *mutable*.

So the difference you observed is because int's are immutable - they cannot be changed.  Whereas lists are mutable - they *can* be changed.

Assigning `a = b` in both cases copies the reference.  It's what happens when you reassign `b`, in this case a new object is created referenced by the left-hand-side.  With a mutable object the object referenced is changed, and it would not matter which reference is used.

Comment: I meant when `b` is reassigned to a changed object, as in the first example `b = 3`.  `b` is no longer referencing 1, the int object value 3 is created and now referenced by `b`.  I've tried to clarify.

Comment: "It's what happens when you reassign b, in this case a new object is created referenced by the left-hand-side." But 'b[0]' is the int 1 and also immutable. Why don't I create a second list then?

Comment: `b[0]`  is a reference, it is just referencing a different immutable object when assigned.

Comment: @bluenorange: The trick when coming from C++ is to stop thinking that names *are* values, but to consider that every name *refers* to an object.  In the C implementation of python, lists are arrays of pointers to python objects (PyObject *).  So `b[0]` is a pointer in the underlying code.  All python objects are referenced using the same pointer type.

Comment: @ cdarke Your last comment cleared it up, I think. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Everything is a reference. All python variables reference objects, all objects can have more than one reference.

The difference you're seeing is between the assignment operator and the `__setitem__` operator. The syntax is similar, but they do different things.

This is an assignment, it updates the reference of variable `var`.

```
var = 'something'
```

This uses setitem, it's essentially a method call on the left hand side object.

```
obj[i] = 'thing'
# is the same as
obj.__setitem__(i, 'thing')
```

What `__setitem__` does depends on the type, but generally it will modify `obj`. In that sense, `b[0] = 3` is more `b.append(3)` than it is like `b = 3`. Immutable types do not have a setitem method and throw an error on the setitem operator.